# AMP Redirect Test with Google Optimize

Tags: amp-html, google-optimize

I am trying to create a redirect test for an AMP page using Google Optimize.  Normally to install Google Optimize on the page you would use something like this:

```
<script src="https://www.googleoptimize.com/optimize.js?id=OPT-'some ID'"></script>
```

Unfortunately, this script tag is not compatible with AMP.  What can I do instead?

Comment: Did you manage to set up a redirect amp AB test with Google Optimize?

Answer (score 0):

On AMP websites, this doesn't work because you have to keep the [AMP guidelines](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/spec/amphtml/) in mind. Look into `<amp-analytics>` and `<amp-experiment>` components to use Google Optimize on AMP sites. The support item [Measure AMP experiments with Optimize](https://developers.google.com/optimize/devguides/amp-experiments) gives you information about the configuration.